# do SugarCRM Community edition support mobile site?

Tags: sugarcrm

I did dig through the SugarCRM CE documentation and forums but could not find answer to this
how to enable mobile browser access for SugarCRM community edition 6.*.* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mobile access of Sugar CRM community edition, you need a third party application like

- [CE Mobile CRM](http://code.google.com/p/ce-mobile-crm/)
- [Rolus Sugar CRM](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/productivity/rolus-sugarcrm_jcoh.html?nav=related)

Answer (score 0):

The CE version does not support Sugar Mobile (see [Edition Comparison](http://media.sugarcrm.com/datasheets/EditionsComparison_CE.pdf)).